# Scrolling to Anchor Tag with php dynamically created page

Tags: php, anchor

I have a page where entries are read from a table and then php generates the divs where each row is displayed - the div's name & id are set to a unique string based on the record #. For example:

When the page is loaded, it is passed the unique anchor string of the record to scroll to in the format: 
href='showpost.php#g50'

When the page loads it correctly shows the url with the anchor but it doesn't scroll.

However, if I put my cursor on the browser's address bar and press `<Enter>` the page scrolls correctly to the record. Oddly enough, `<F5>` and `<Ctrl-R>` will not work (Firefox 16).

I am guessing that the page being dynamically created has something to do with it. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: It is fairly involved. I will work on creating isolated php code to see if I can duplicate it.

Comment: That would be great. It's pretty hard to help without seeing anything specific about your problem - now the only people that can help you are those who have encountered the exact same problem.

Comment: Hmmm these may be obvious but, some browsers just take a while before jumping to the anchor (especially if you have a lot of content) or perhaps malformed anchor tags? Or if you're using javascript maybe the scroll event is firing too soon before the page has loaded

Comment: I've got it figured out. Sometimes it takes posting a question to realize how to debug it. What I found was that I had a java script onload scrolling to 0 and conflicting with the anchor. Thanks for the encouragement to post code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use a simple javascript call to scroll to an anchor. You can call Javascript code from anywhere in the page, so to be safe, you could put it at the end of the page after the PHP has generated all the anchors.

```
<?php 
    // php generation code here
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hashSplit = location.href.split('#');
    var curHash= hashSplit[1];
    window.location.hash = curHash;
</script>
```

Or if you already know what the anchor of the page is going to be via php you can do it even easier.

```
<?php
    $anchor = "home";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.hash = "<?= $anchor; ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very useful example, thanks SISYN.
But I have my version

```
let hashSplit = location.href.split('#');
let curHash = hashSplit[1];
if(typeof curHash !== 'undefined') {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + curHash).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```